# Clear cache after flyway migration script execution

Tags: spring-boot, redis, flyway

I need to refresh my Redis cache every time some insert/update happens in the DB through a flyway migration script. Is there any way to achieve this? My application is written in Spring Boot.

Comment: Is the update done using the same application or another application ?

Comment: Cache is external

Answer (score 0):

You can use help of `cacheManager`.

```
public void clearCache() {
    cacheManager.getCacheNames()
                .parallelStream()
                .forEach(n -> cacheManager.getCache(n).clear());
}
```

Also check for documentation.

[RedisCacheManagerBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/cache/RedisCacheManager.RedisCacheManagerBuilder.html#initialCacheNames-java.util.Set-)

Comment: How do i trigger this when a flyway migration occur? I am looking for a way to connect migration script execution and cache clear method